# Latencies issue with my Jersey Client

Tags: jersey-client

I have some trouble with my Jersey client (2.14).
I sent requests to my server (Jetty 8.1) every 100 ms. For 10 seconds there is no problems but every 10 seconds I have a request which remains blocked 2 seconds...

The trouble doesn't seem to come from jetty ...

Somebody got similar issue ?

```
private class PostJob implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (start) {
            try {
                final HttpData take = daQueu.take();
                final String path = take.path();
                final Entity<Object> arg = take.arg();
                for (final Map.Entry<String, ClientHandler> e : clients.entrySet()) {
                    final ClientHandler clientHandler = e.getValue();
                    long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    Invocation.Builder request = null;
                    if (REQUEST_CACHE.containsKey(path)) {
                        request = REQUEST_CACHE.get(path);
                    } else {
                        LOGGER.debug("build new request");
                        request = clientHandler.client.target(path).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
                        REQUEST_CACHE.put(path, request);
                    }
                    Response post = request.post(arg);
                    LOGGER.debug("Execution delay for sending: {}", System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTimeMillis);
                    post.close();
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I'm pretty sure that it doesn't come from Jetty Server... (but ....).
My server is embedded in Karaf container and is started by Pax-web feature.

Following a part of my server code which register my servlets:

```
final ResourceConfig restServletConf = new ResourceConfig()
                  .register(JacksonFeature.class).register(MultiPartFeature.class).register(SseFeature.class).register(JsonProcessingFeature.class);
            restServletConf.registerInstances(restResources);
            final HttpServlet restServlet = new ServletContainer(restServletConf);
            try {
                webContainer.registerServlet(conf.servletPath, restServlet, null, restService);
                logService.log(LogService.LOG_INFO, "Serving JAX-RS resources from " + conf.servletPath);

                // Servlet filters must be started after the REST servlet
                // (constraint from PAX-Web's WebContainer API).
                restService.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logService.log(LogService.LOG_ERROR, "Failed to start JAX-RS servlet", e);
            }
```

Comment: I Think that this may be due to a reset of the connection but I don't know I can resolve it .... perhaps "keep-alive" parameter ...

Comment: have you reproduiced the bug using CURL ? If Yes, can you provide server side code please ?

Comment: To be more precise: if I run my jetty server locally (127.0.0.1) I have no problem but if run it on a remote computer I have the problem ... I run my client and my server on windows 7.

Comment: Hi Julien, if you want some help. Please share your code (empty of all specific job), I'll try to reproduice. What can make jetty slow is garbadge collecting. Have you tryed to take a look with jmx in order to see memory consumption?

Comment: I check memory usage and is OK and does not appear due to garbage activity. The the problem is so regular that I bet on limitation in Jersey Client. Every 100 requests then 2 secondes delay remaining.

Comment: 1. I would recommand you to embedd jetty in a jar and try to execute it directly  as a jetty embedded in jar (do not use karaf /pax web) in order to see if you have the same latencies problems. 2. in your client code, I can't see the sleep method  that enables you to execute every 100ms. Can you add on this code after getting client handler please. Can you give me the stdout prints in order to see the traces. Thanks